# I am trying to make 2 stage op amp that amplifies audio to a speaker

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-design

I am new to electrical engineering and was given a school project to create a basic circuit that amplifies sound to a speaker. In the process of trying to solve this problem I've come across several different hurdles.

For one, I designed a circuit after gathering information from youtube tutorials and I can't even test if it is functioning properly cause I am not sure if my speaker is working or the circuit is just wrong. I also dont know how to connect an epe speaker to a breadboard (TRRS.)

Any kind of help would be appreciated, especially with regards to confirming if my circuit is correct.

I used two different op amps to get the two stage amplification. The output of the first op amp should be the input of the second.  The voltage should be between 5-12V for the input. Did I ground the correct segment? Should I add a seperate battery for the second op amp or will that generate more noise? I put the capacitor there to reduce noise, should I add more?

[image]

Comment: The second op-amp is trying to have infinite gain and you'll probably end up turning all your sound into square waves, is that intended?

Comment: Most op-amps have difficulty driving a speaker, causing audio distortion starting at very low signal amplitude. The cause is insufficient current at the output pin...many op-amps limit current for self-protection. Where current-limiting sets in, distortion results. Headphones are often an easier load than a speaker, providing sufficient loudness before distortion begins.

Comment: An op-amp is not powerful enough to drive a speaker. Depends on speaker and op-amp though, but unlikely under normal circumstances. Also you can't use an inverting amplifier if you ground the positive input and provide only single-ended supply voltage.

Comment: What do you mean by "speaker"? A big-dia, powerful (e.g. 12-in 50W) speaker or a headphone speaker? With an op amp, you can drive only the latter.

Comment: to clarify i meant a mini earpiece speaker, nothing large

Comment: no its not, im only trying to amplify the incoming signals, How can i fix that? @user253751

Comment: There's another problem with your circuit: The incoming signal has positive and negative peaks, and the signal is entering to the op amp directly (i.e. without any DC bias), so the op amp should have split supply (e.g. ±9V), not single 9V supply. The negative peaks will be chopped off so your signal will be completely distorted.

Comment: @ttomtt first I have to wonder: do you know what *exactly* you are trying to do, and what an op-amp does? If you do understand both, then we just have to bridge that gap. Otherwise there is more to learn first...

Comment: @user253751 Im not 100 percent on how everything works to be honest, but i also cant just come and ask you to "do my homework for me" so to speak.  after trying to read my textbook and looking at tutorials on youtube I thought this would be the next best thing

Comment: Can we also ask why you decided to use two op-amps instead of for example 0 or 1 or 3 or 4? Just out of curiosity.

Comment: @RohatKılıç ahh i see that makes sense, for some reason I though just grounding it would be fine, even though ive seen the diagram and it does require a negative voltage input, Thanks

Comment: @user253751 i tried using zero op amps actually. I started using transistors at first but then gave up cause the wiring seemed too complex

Answer (score 1):

Circuit is incorrect.
For the first opamp in the signal chain, grounding the non-inverting input (+ input) is wrong, if you intend to power the opamp with a single +9V DC supply. The +input should be half-way between +9V and GND, like the circuit below. A capacitor C2 is added so that this voltage remains fairly constant. R3, R4 have large resistance so that a battery supply is not stressed.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmTgUp.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

For C1 (a polarized capacitor), its "+"end should face the opamp, not the input signal.
The potentiometer can have a larger value, like 10k so that the opamp needn't drive it with a lot of current...the limited current available at opamp output pin should mostly go to the headphone.
I have added an output resistor R5 so that the opamp is not stressed.
Capacitor polarity for C3 must face the opamp output pin. Headphones would be connected between "Out" and GND (bottom of +9V supply).
Some opamps may work better if headphones are connected between "Out" and +9V, in which case polarity of C3 should be reversed.

Answer (score 0):

Your original (Falstaf?) schematic was a negative image so I changed it to a normal black on white positive. It had many errors:
[image]

Comment: The 2nd op amp does not have to be an audio PA as the load is nothing different than an earphone i.e. a few tens of milliwatts and an op amp can drive it.

Comment: The max output current of many opamps is only 15mA peak and many earphones are 32 ohms. then maximum output levels are low.

Answer (score 0):

Feed your device signal through an LM386 IC to drive the speaker. This IC is rated at about 700 mw.

[image]

You can use two of these chips to make a stereo amplifier. Sound quality is decent with this but can be improved with additional components. Chip will provide 20% voltage gain as shown. To increase gain to 200, add a 1200 to 2200 ohm resistor and a 10 mF polarized capacitor between pins 1 and 8. Pin 1 gets one side of the resistor other connected to + side of cap. The negative side of cap goes to pin 8. It can be run on 9 or 12 volts DC. If your power supply output is higher then these voltages, I would recommend using a 12 volt regulator to power the components as a safety measure to keep chip overheating to a minimum depending on the power your chosen speaker will need to operate. Use a heat sink on the regulator if needed. I have also used a modification of this circuit to operate LEDs to light and synchronize with music. Its temperature range is 0-70 degrees C. and max 150 degrees C. junction temperature and 10 second duration soldering on package. Test your speaker with a 1.5 volt battery touched to its terminals for a short time. If the speaker is good, it will make a thumping or crackling noise if it is ok then immediately disconnect it. You may also check it with an ohmmeter and it should be either 8 or 4 ohms. These are the values used with this circuit.